# background not showing in firefox when using background-size

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to set a background with background-size using css, but the only browser that it doesn't work in right now is Firefox. Do you have any idea why this doesn't work?

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    color:#000; 
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    background-image: url(/gfx/bg.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100% !important;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='/gfx/bg.png',
    sizingMethod='scale');

    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='/gfx/bg.png',
    sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Comment: Provide JSfiddle with your HTML, images and CSS.

Comment: It works fine [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/vsfWK/) so it must be something else

Comment: Your image path is wrong. Show us your tree list view.

Comment: seems to be problem with this part `/gfx/bg.png`

Comment: Also [no prefix is required for any browser](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts). I find your syntax curious though, specifying `100% 100%`. Are you not looking for `background-size:cover`?

Comment: All other browser do work. Then it can't be the images path I, right?

Comment: Can you put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes `cover` and `100% 100%` are two different properties.

Comment: I know, and usually people looking for `cover` but not knowing it exists try to mimick it with `100% 100%`.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I know cover exists, but it's indeed a different effect han what i'm looking for.

Comment: why `-moz-background-size: 100% 100% !important;` ? Even you mention it there is no need of `!important` as per the context posted above.

Comment: `background-size` [is supported since FF4 (or FF3.6 with `-moz-`)](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size), so there shouldn't be a problem there. One suggestion: Try taking out the IE-specific `filter` style; I recall some versions of Firefox had an issue where they would see it as invalid CSS (which is true) and that then causing other styles around it to not be rendered correctly. (I thought that was only older FF versions that did this, but might be worth taking ten seconds to try it).

Comment: @Spudley: I just noticed the IE filter causes an issue when trying to transition the background-size, but using the property alone didn't cause an issue. Strange ..

Comment: @Adrift: Yes, strange. Although given that the syntax of `filter` is invalid CSS (mainly due to the colon after progID), I can see how it can cause parsing errors. That's why I generally prefer to use the polyfill or fallback options rather than the `filter` style.

Answer (score 0):

```
src='/gfx/bg.png'
```

this is wrong. 
If `gfx` is your first image it should be this :

```
   src='gfx/bg.png'
```

Comment: maybe the image is stored in a subfolder of the website root in which case /gfx/bg.png is completely valid.

Comment: gfx is indeed my images folder